# Proper usage of a global variable in Python

Tags: python

I'm working on a simple password generating script and i'm essentially trying to use a global string variable called `password` but i'm unsure if i'm using it properly because i'm getting this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\bkrause080\Desktop\Free Time Projects\LearningPythonProjects\passwordGenerator.py", line 34, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__": main()
  File "C:\Users\bkrause080\Desktop\Free Time Projects\LearningPythonProjects\passwordGenerator.py", line 32, in main
    print "Your strong password is: ", strong(lowercase, uppercase, numbers, specials)
  File "C:\Users\bkrause080\Desktop\Free Time Projects\LearningPythonProjects\passwordGenerator.py", line 22, in strong
    password += random.choice(lowercase).rstrip('\n') + random.choice(uppercase).rstrip('\n') + random.choice(numbers).rstrip('\n') + random.choice(specials).rstrip('\n')
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'password' referenced before assignment
```

Here is my source code:

```
import random

lowercase = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
uppercase = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
specials = ['~','!','@','#','$','%','%', '^', '&','&','*','(',')','?','<','>','[',']']
password = ""

def weak():
    with open("EnglishWords.txt", "r") as f:
        weakWords = f.readlines()
    password = random.choice(weakWords).rstrip('\n') + random.choice(weakWords).rstrip('\n')
    return password

def medium(lowercase, numbers):
    for i in range(0,4):
        password += random.choice(lowercase).rstrip('\n') + random.choice(numbers).rstrip('\n')
    return password

def strong(lowercase, uppercase, numbers, specials):
    for j in range(0,3):
        password += random.choice(lowercase).rstrip('\n') + random.choice(uppercase).rstrip('\n') + random.choice(numbers).rstrip('\n') + random.choice(specials).rstrip('\n')
    return password

def main():
    passStrength = raw_input("What strength password would you like? (weak/medium/strong): ")
    if passStrength == 'weak':
        print "Your weak password is: \n", weak()
    elif passStrength == 'medium':
        print "Your medium password is: ", medium(lowercase, numbers)
    elif passStrength == 'strong':
        print "Your strong password is: ", strong(lowercase, uppercase, numbers, specials)

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

I'm very new to python and only really have experience in java and C so any info would be very appreciated!

Comment: Did you google the error? There are dozens of good duplicates for this problem on Stack Overfow. Some of them right there -->

Comment: Minor note: you can spare yourself some boilerplate if you `import string` and check out `string.ascii_lowercase`, `string.digits`, `string.punctuation` etc.